# View thumbnail cache in OS X

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

Is it possible to somehow see the cached files by QuickLook?

I have found that some data is stored in

```
/private/var/folders/xx/xxxxxxx/x/com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache
```

In here I found a index.sqlite which lists the path of the file (where it was when viewed) and a fs_id which looks like:

```
/.file/id=1234567.123
```

And then I got stuck...

Can I find this cache file somehow and view it ?

Answer (score 2):

thumbnail-cache will be random, it will always have the name **com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache**. So i think you have already found the right location.

There you find the **index.sqlite** file is a SQLite database-file containing two tables: *thumbnails and files*.

The files table contains the name, path, file-identifier, and volume-identifier of each file tracked by the database.

The *thumbnails table* contains information about each thumbnail, including the file to which it relates (as stored in the files table) and the offset of its data, which is **stored as a raw bitmap** in the thumbnails.data file.

may [this](http://encase-forensic-blog.guidancesoftware.com/2014/05/examination-of-mac-os-x-quick-look.html?m=1) will solve your question, because all of the Infos are from this Page.

Comment: Thank you. I read that earlier. The image data seems to be in the thumbnails.data file. So I guess I need to read that file and slice out the appropriate portions of it.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: I will extend my answer soon.done mow :)