# Will anything bad happen if I just delete my thumbnail cache?

Tags: finder, macos, quicklook

I keep data on a thumb drive and sometimes my laptop gets hot running quicklookd presumably *trying to make* thumbnails of all of the files on the thumb drive. The high runner file types are images, pdfs and JSONs. I am guessing if I kept them zipped I could avoid the thumbnail generation but that's a different question.

I've found `index.sqlite` and `thumbnails.data` in the private folder `com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache`. [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/299829/143729) may address my question indirectly but I don't really know what to do or what will happen.

If I just go and delete `index.sqlite` and `thumbnails.data` and then restart, will my computer blow up? Will it have to generate all thumbnails for files on my start-up HD again?

I have never used [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) so I don't think I should try to modify this pair, even with a script, and I understand that next time I use the data quicklookd may fire up again. Still I'd like to know what would likely happen if I deleted this pair of files.

Comment: if you can make your computer `blow up` lets us know :) but on more serious note,  would you consider disabling QuickLook ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I guess I'd first have to ask "What happens if I just disabled QuickLook?" because I don't know. Is that something I could do just during each period that the thumb drive being connected? Here though I am primarily asking about deleting these two files in order to *remove the existing cached thumbnails*.

Comment: as you know the Finder needs the QuickLook and without it it wont be able to show you. I think that is all it will happen. At the moment I do not know how to disable it just for the external drive.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a guess, but I'm assuming if you switch off the icon preview & preview column, then the system would have no need to generate preview icons...

You might need to do this for all 3 view types, Column, Icon & List, from View menu  > Show View Options  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd> 
Example [using a RAMDisk, as it was just conveniently populated]...

[image]

Comment: That's interesting! I will give this a try as soon as I have a chance and let you know how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: I never did let you know on this, and now I don't remember how it went. I'm back in a similar situation so I'll try it again. I've added a bounty because I'm still interested in the answer to the title *Will anything bad happen if I just delete my thumbnail cache?*

Answer (score 2):

No, nothing 'bad' will happen. However, the OS is likely to start re-populating the cache database, which may mean more ramping up of CPU cycles for quicklookd.

Comment: thanks! Is this an educated guess or from experience, or can this be sourced from somewhere?

Comment: @uhoh Never tried it, but make a new User account, standard and do the test ?

Comment: @uhoh Caches are for filling up. The OS wants to create caches: the idea being that once made, having them speeds things up.

Comment: @benwiggy I would expect it would most likely be okay, yes. But I've asked the question here and then added the bounty to find out for sure before I do it. I'm hoping for a definitive answer, but maybe nobody knows for sure.

Comment: @ankii I don't know how to do that, and it might not work because I don't have a lot of extra space at the moment. It's possible that one or more people here would be more experienced and could give that a try. (also see above). Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh Does Tetsujin's answer stop quicklookd from ramping up? If you're not generating the previews, I would not expect it to do the work. Also, are all these files inside folders, or on the top level of the volume? I think we need to establish that quicklookd is working because of your thumb drive, and not some other reason.

Comment: @benwiggy okay two things; 1) it is without question the insertion the thumb drive that sends quicklookd into overdrive. This is established and repeatable. 2) after posting the original question and reading the answer, I'd gone on to read more about thumbnail caches and found that they are a (mild) security concern. So I'd still like an answer to the question in the title which is reiterated in the bounty.